# Regular expression to select words not starting with one of a set of prefixes

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a regular expression that selects all words that do NOT begin with one of a set of prefixes.

For example, with allowable word prefixes `jan|feb|mar|apr` I'd want to match the text in bold in the following string:

"**in** january **or** feb **I** marched **off to see** april"

I managed to select the exact opposite of what I'd like, matching words beginning with the prefixes:

`(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)(?:\w+)?`

I also managed to select all words that were not the prefixes themselves, but this doesn't handle all words *beginning with* the prefixes, just words that *are* the prefix:

`[a-z]+\b(?<!\bjan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)`

The ultimate goal is to strip all words that do not begin with one of the prefixes from the input string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The ultimate goal is to strip all words that do not begin with one of the prefixes from the input string.

You may use this regex for matching:

```sh
\b(?!(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|ju[nl]|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))\w+\s*
```

and replace it with an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpKqhv/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|ju[nl]|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)`: Match of the 3 letter month prefix
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces